# How can I update the source of a bound custom dependency property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I have a custom DepenencyProperty which determines a UserControl's visibility. It is usually bound to a boolean value, however I would like to set it False when the Escape key is hit.

The problem is, I don't want to overwrite the binding, I want to update the bindings source value. How can I do this in code behind?

For example, with this XAML

```
<local:MyControl IsVisibile="{Binding IsControlVisible}" />
```

I want to update the value of `IsControlVisible` to false, not `MyControl.IsVisible`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be possible via [`BindingExpressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.aspx), try something like this:

```
private void MyControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        var source = sender as FrameworkElement;
        var expression = source.GetBindingExpression(UIElement.IsVisibleProperty);
        (expression.DataItem as MyDataItem).IsControlVisible = false;
    }
}
```

(*If you do not reuse the `UIElement.IsVisibleProperty` you need to specify it via `MyControl.IsVisibleProperty` of course*)

---

Here is a reflection-using method:

```
var source = sender as FrameworkElement;
var expression = source.GetBindingExpression(UIElement.IsVisibleProperty);
var dataType = expression.DataItem.GetType();
dataType.GetProperties().Single(x => x.Name == expression.ParentBinding.Path.Path)
        .SetValue(expression.DataItem, false, null);
```

Comment: The `MyDataItem` class is not a static class, so I don't think this will work. Multiple ViewModels contain this type of control and each use different boolean value to determine visibility.

Comment: `MyDataItem` is not supposed to be a static class, this is just a cast to your object which holds the property `IsControlVisible`.

Comment: @HB I can't do that though because I don't know what class the Visibility is bound to, or even what the boolean property is called. ViewModelA might contain this UserControl and bind to the property `ViewModelA.IsControlVisible` while ViewModelB might bind to `ViewModelB.CanEdit`

Comment: Yuck... Anyway, i added a method which hopefully works in your case.

Answer (score 5):

WPF 4? Use [`SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx):

```
this.SetCurrentValue(IsControlVisibleProperty, false);
```

This *won't* overwrite the binding, but will instead push `false` to the binding source.

Comment: That doesn't work. It looks like it replaces the Binding on the property with `false`, so I lose the binding

Comment: Are you sure you used `SetCurrentValue` and not `SetValue`?

Comment: Just noticed that the mode of the Binding should be set to `TwoWay` when using this method. Otherwise the source will not be changed.

Comment: @HB Yes I was using SetCurrentValue. The BindingMode was left to default and I'm not sure if it defaults to OneWay or TwoWay

Comment: @Kent Boogaart - `SetCurrentValue` is not there in WPF 3.5. Is there any alternative of not loosing binding in WPF 3.5 and update the target at same time?

Comment: Custom properties default to OneWay, Unless you set the FrameworkPropertyMetadata flag to FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault.